# Hiding and showing iADs makes my view disappear

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, iad

I am using ios7 and I am enabled iAds with "self.canDisplayBannerAds"

The iAd basically reshapes the view when it shifts in or when it shifts out.  However, When the banner shifts, my view Moves off screen!

In my story board, I put my view outside of the screen.  And when the user presses a button, I set its frame property so that it exists inside of the screen.  But when the iAd shifts in or out, the View travels back to its original place in the story board.

How can I prevent my view from sliding off the screen?

---

Update:
I tried simply adding a view programatically.  and placed it in the same place as the one I made in Interface Builder.  Initially they both move offscreen and on screen when commanded.  however, once the iAd shifts in and out, the view I made in interface builder will slide out.  The view I made programatically will stay put.

My best guess at this point was Auto layout or something to do with constraints.  The IB view was sliding out rather than simply disappearing and It definitely was not using UIView's animation methods.  Thus the only other thing that I could think of that could cause animations to happen are constrains.  (eg rotating a view with view's that have constriaints will automatically resize in a smooth fashion.

so I took a look at the constraints of the view by calling the constraints method in an NSLog.  It printed out a huge list of constraints.  I did not add these explicitly, which means they were added automatically.

There may be a connection between these constraints.  The question now is, why is the iAD banner triggering the view to basically spring back to its former place?

Answer (score 0):

When the banner shifts in and out, it will layout the subviews. Views without any constraints are given automatic constraints.  These constraints place it in the same location as it's place in the xib.

You can try changing the constraints.